# Returning non-distinct rows based on multiple criteria SQL, MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table called MASTER that is imported from another source. It contains these fields:
FIELD A, FIELD B, FIELD C, FIELD D, FIELD E, FIELD F, FIELD G, FIELD H, FIELD I, FIELD J, and FIELD K

I'm trying to design a query that will return every instance where first, FIELD D is NOT DISTINCT. I want all records that occur more than once returned. Then from there, in that set, I want to return everything where, for each distinct FIELD D record, there are multiple results for FIELD I.

FIELD D is essentially a numeric public key. FIELD I is a numeric status code. The goal is to scan for any case where there are two status codes attached to one public key.

Below is my best attempt so far. It does return the set I want, but there are some additional public keys that are returned. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
SELECT DISTINCT PREP1.FIELD_D, PREP1.FIELD_I
FROM (SELECT [MASTER].FIELD_D AS FIELD_D, [MASTER].FIELD_I AS FIELD_I
    FROM [MASTER] GROUP BY [MASTER].FIELD_D, [MASTER].FIELD_I) AS
         PREP1 
INNER JOIN (SELECT [MASTER].FIELD_D AS FIELD_D, [MASTER].FIELD_I AS
              FIELD_I
            FROM [MASTER]
            GROUP BY [MASTER].FIELD_D, [MASTER].FIELD_I
            HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)  AS PREP2 ON PREP1.FIELD_D = 
                                     PREP2.FIELD_D
GROUP BY PREP1.FIELD_D, PREP1.FIELD_I
```

EDIT: I whipped up this little example. Columns A and B represent the type of data I will have. Column C lists the ones I want returned. You will notice that there is an example of duplicates in Column A, but their related value in Column B is the same, so I don't need those.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    table {
      font-family: arial, sans-serif;
      border-collapse: collapse;
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    td,
    th {
      border: 1px solid #dddddd;
      text-align: left;
      padding: 8px;
    }
    
    tr:nth-child(even) {
      background-color: #dddddd;
    }
    </style>
    <body><table><tr><th>COLUMN A</th><th>COLUMN B</th><th>COLUMN C</th></tr><tr><td>00000000</td><td>0</td><td>""</td></tr><tr><td>00000000</td><td>0</td><td>""</td></tr><tr><td>00000001</td><td>1</td><td>""</td></tr><tr><td>00000002</td><td>1</td><td>RETURN</td></tr><tr><td>00000002</td><td>2</td><td>RETURN</td></tr><tr><td>00000003</td><td>1</td><td>""</td></tr><tr><td>00000004</td><td>1</td><td>""</td></tr><tr><td>00000004</td><td>1</td><td>""</td></tr><tr><td>00000005</td><td>3</td><td>""</td></tr><tr><td>00000006</td><td>3</td><td>""</td></tr><tr><td>00000007</td><td>0</td><td>""</td></tr><tr><td>00000008</td><td>0</td><td>""</td></tr><tr><td>00000009</td><td>1</td><td>RETURN</td></tr><tr><td>00000009</td><td>2</td><td>RETURN</td></tr><tr><td>00000010</td><td>0</td><td>""</td></tr></table></body></html>
```

Comment: If you provide some sample data and expected results it may be easier to provide a valuable answer.

Comment: I would remove the having filter and include the count field as a column in the subquery you inner join to and then filter the outer query off that

Comment: I have included an example table if you run the code snippet. Also, Daniel, either I didn't understand you, or it hasn't worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is what ended up working. Hopefully it makes sense.

```
SELECT MASTER.FIELDA, MASTER.FIELDB, MASTER.FIELDC, MASTER.FIELDD, MASTER.FIELDF
FROM (
[MASTER] AS MASTER 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT PREP1.FIELDD, COUNT(PREP1.FIELDD) AS [COUNT] 
    FROM (
        SELECT FIELDD, FIELDF 
        FROM [MASTER] 
        INNER JOIN FILTER ON [MASTER].FIELDB =
             FILTER.FIELDB 
        GROUP BY FIELDD, FIELDF) AS PREP1 
    )  GROUP BY FIELDD ) AS PREP2 ON MASTER.FIELDD = PREP2.FIELDD
INNER JOIN FILTER ON MASTER.FIELDB = tblSAClients.FundSponsor
WHERE (((PREP2.COUNT)>1))
ORDER BY MASTER.FIELDD DESC;
```